# pfSense Traffic Graph: total doesn't add up

Tags: pfsense

I am new to pfSense, but my network and monitoring skills are okay. I am trying to understand the Traffic Graph. I have read the [documentation](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Traffic_Graph).

As far as I understand the graph on the left side should display the total throughput on the selected interface. And the list on the right side should display the details for the hosts using the most bandwidth. However the totals do not add up. On the following screenshot the top 3 "in" hosts use 1.7MB/s, and one "out" host uses 1.8MB/s. But on the graph  "in" is less than 500kB/s, and "out" is less than 100kB/s.

What am I missing?

[image]

I am using the following version.

```
2.3.4-RELEASE (amd64) 
built on Wed May 03 15:13:29 CDT 2017 
FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p19
```

Answer (score 2):

Graph is in MBytes, chart is in Mbits.  I found your question because I'm trying to find out how to change the graph to Mbits.

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know how you found this information before I accept your answer?